# Не выводится embed.set_footer Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Не выводится строчка embed.set_footer
Должно быть так:

[image: Должно быть так]

А получается вот так:

[image: А получается вот так]

Вот код:

```
#команда !kick 
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    channel=client.get_channel(866345867908218890)
    await member.kick( reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Кик пользователя ', description=f'Пользователь{member.mention} был кикнут!', colour=discord.Color.red()))
    embed.set_footer(text = 'Был кикнут администратором {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)  
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переделать вот так:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    channel = client.get_channel(866345867908218890)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(title='Кик пользователя ', 
                          description=f'Пользователь{member.mention} был кикнут!',
                          colour=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Был кикнут администратором {ctx.author.name}', 
                     icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```